# How can I make Feathers (Express-based API Framework) Return Error Responses

Tags: feathersjs

I've read the Feathers book, so I know that to create an error response I simply instantiate the appropriate `feathers-errors` class:

```
import {BadRequest} from 'feathers-errors';
const errorResponse = new BadRequest(`foo`, `bar`);
```

However, I'm having difficulty returning that error response to the user.  Even when I create an endpoint that does nothing but return an error response ...

```
class SomeService {
    create(data) {
        return new BadRequest(`foo`, `bar`);
    }
}
```

it doesn't work: instead of getting an error response, I get no response, and inside the Chrome debugger I can see that the response is pending (until it eventually times out and becomes an ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE).

I tried reading about Express error handling, and in the examples I saw people used `next` to wrap the the response.  However, `next` comes from the error handler, and I'm not sure where in my Feathers code I can get that `next` function.

If anyone could help explain (using `next` or not) how I can return a *complete*, not pending, error response, I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your services have to return a promise. If your code is not asynchronous you can turn it into a promise with [Promise.resolve](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/resolve) and [Promise.reject](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/reject):

```
class SomeService {
    create(data) {
        return Promise.reject(new BadRequest(`foo`, `bar`));
    }
}
```

Also make sure you registered the Express error handler to get nicely formatted errors:

```
const errorHandler = require('feathers-errors/handler');

// Last in the chain
app.use(errorHandler);
```

There is also more information in the [error handling chapter](https://docs.feathersjs.com/middleware/error-handling.html).